# How often must a worker in a spice store say "Borei Minei B'Samim"?

Tags: halacha, blessing, time, employment, smell

How often must a worker in a spice store say "Borei Minei B'Samim"?Pretty simple question.

I assume that once per day? Or is he exempt because he is expose to it constantly and this is part of his job? He has no intention to specifically smell spices, because he works there. In a sense, perhaps, after a while, he becomes "immune" to the smell. Maybe, then, he is exempt?

Comment: FWIW it's _Minei Vesamim_.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently only once. Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim siman 217 siff 1. No difference is made between welling in to buy or to sell. The Mishna Berurah brings an opinion not to make the bracha at all unless he has intention to derive pleasure, but disagrees with this being that the incense are made to be enjoyed and he is enjoying them. No mention is made of immunity.